# PHP-OOP | Not accessing database

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I'm trying to make this code access a certain row in the database and pull "title" from it to update public $Title in the UserBlog class, but, it's not doing so.

The database connection is definitely working as it worked procedually, but OOP is messing it up.

```
$ID       = $db->real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['ID']))); // Page ID

class UserBlog
{
public $Title;
public $BannerImage;
public $ID;

public function GenerateBlog() {
    $FetchBlogDetails = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM UserBlogs WHERE ID = '$this->ID'");
    $FBL = mysqli_fetch_object($FetchBlogDetails);
    $this->Title = $FBL->Title;
}

public function FetchBlog() {

    return $this->Title;
    return $this->ID;

}


};

$GetBlog = new UserBlog();
$GetBlog->ID = $ID;

$GetBlog->GenerateBlog();

echo $GetBlog->Title;
echo $GetBlog->ID;
```

Comment: Please explain what part isn't working, what you're getting and what you're expecting. For reference simply using classes / objects does not OOP make.

Comment: You do realize that the FetchBlog function will only return the title and never reach the return ID part? Consider returning them in an associative array. Also I suggest using capitals for ClassNames and non-capitals for functionNames, will make it easier on the eye.

Comment: Why would it not reach ID..

Comment: Because your function FetchBlog terminates upon return $this->Title;

Comment: .. I don't follow - I only started looking at OOP yesterday.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OOP, just basic functions. Read: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: @JonStirling so if I would simply use classes or objects what would it make then occording to your reference?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$db doesn't exist in the scope of your method. You could inject it when calling the method.

```
class UserBlog
{
public $Title;
public $BannerImage;
public $ID;
public function GenerateBlog($db) {
    $FetchBlogDetails = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM UserBlogs WHERE ID = '$this->ID'");
    $FBL = mysqli_fetch_object($FetchBlogDetails);
    $this->Title = $FBL->Title;
}
//...
}
$GetBlog = new UserBlog();
$GetBlog->ID = $ID;
$GetBlog->GenerateBlog($db);
```

Comment: This worked, but when I put the class into a seperate file and include it with index.php which is where I generate new UserBlog() and echo the values, nothing happens?

Comment: It works because you add the $db object into the scope of your method, before doing this the method doesn't know $db exists and can't use it.